# How to update a record by checking a value in another record in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

I have a table:

```
ID      DATE            RANGE       STATUS
--------------------------------------------
123     30-SEP-2019     000         C
123     30-SEP-2019     001         NULL
345     25-SEP-2019     000         C
345     30-SEP-2019     001         NULL
567     30-SEP-2019     000         C
567     30-SEP-2019     001         NULL
789     27-SEP-2019     000         C
789     30-SEP-2019     001         NULL
```

Records with the same ID (for ex., 123) considered as same record with different RANGE. 
I need to update the STATUS of 001 RANGE records to Y for which 000 RANGE record should have the date as 30-SEP-2019.

Ex. Update query should update the STATUS to 'Y' for the record with the ID - '123' and RANGE - '001', because for the ID - '123' with the RANGE - '000' record's DATE is '30-SEP-2019'. Also it should update the STATUS of 001 RANGE record with the ID - 567.

It should not update the STATUS of 001 RANGE for the IDs 789 & 345, because those 000 RANGE record's DATE is not equal to 30-SEP-2019.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated subquery with filtering comes to mind:

```
update t
    set status = (select t2.status
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.range = '000'
                 )
    where date = '2019-09-30' and range = '001';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry the question was wrong, I need to update the status as Y

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if Gordon's answer is correct, you could use a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE T1
SET status = T2.Status
FROM YourTable T1
     JOIN YourTable T2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE T1.[date] = '20190930'
  AND T1.range = '001'
  AND T2.range = '000';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do an update with a self join:

```
update t
set status = 'Y'
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on t.id = tt.id and t.date = tt.date and t.status is null and tt.status is not null
```

You can add conditions in a WHERE clause specifically for the ranges that you want to change like:

```
WHERE t.range = '001' and tt.range = '000'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f6d32a4b1be59372e961c82b74956746).
Results:

```
 ID | DATE        | RANGE | STATUS
--: | :---------- | ----: | :-----
123 | 30-SEP-2019 |     0 | C     
123 | 30-SEP-2019 |     1 | Y     
345 | 25-SEP-2019 |     0 | C     
345 | 30-SEP-2019 |     1 | null 
567 | 30-SEP-2019 |     0 | C     
567 | 30-SEP-2019 |     1 | Y     
789 | 27-SEP-2019 |     0 | C     
789 | 30-SEP-2019 |     1 | null
```